# Notes -- Can we prevent editing after Creation

Tags: apex, trigger

We have enabled Notes and would like to prevent editing after creation. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Without this information, your question is likely to be closed without answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, After creation you cannot prevent notes from editing.  Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdaSMUAZ/controlling-permission-on-notes-attachments-irrespective-of-objective-perm).

Notes & attachments permissions are attached with object level permission on profile. If object has CRUD permission you would need to make appropriate changes like edit/read only of object on profile level.  You can use custom validation logic to prevent users from editing notes after creation.